# When should I use "shall" versus "will"?

Tags: differences, future, will-future, shall-future

Which is the correct use of these two words, and in which context should one be used rather than the other?

Comment: Another interesting and important question is why we have these two words to form the future tense? What's the origin of the words, and why have both survived? Will both survive?

Comment: It is very interesting to see answers to related question that @Edward Tanguay included in his answer: **"I often have wondered in which parts of the world (England?) and which social echelons using "shall" in statements is actually still practiced by native speakers?"**

Comment: In the US defense industry, product specifications contain the word "shall" to identify contractual obligations as in "The system **shall** handle 100 widgets per second". If the word "will" replaced shall in that sentence, the requirement would not be considered a contractual obligation. The people who write system specifications and statements of work use "shall" throughout engineering documents to indicate those capabilities the system **must** have to meet the spec. Yes the language sounds stilted, but every "shall" reinforces the contractual nature of the requirement.

Comment: @John S: not just in the defense industry, it's common in formal requirement specifications. (e.g. in the medical products industry as well)

Comment: When you attend your local Renaissance Festival.

Comment: It's quite long, but @Cerberus's answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/why-do-we-say-supposed-to-for-should-have), which is probably the best answer I've ever seen here on ELU, seems relevant.

Comment: See  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260922/when-should-one-use-shall-and-will

Comment: In modern American English, _shall_ is rarely used. It's limited to two first-person idiomatic question constructions, one singular and one plural; both have pragmatic uses. The plural construction is used as an invitation: _Shall we dance? Shall we get lunch tomorrow?_. The singular one is used as an offer of assistance: _Shall I open the window? Shall I turn out the lights?_. Other than these, _shall_ in speech is perceived as a British affectation.

Answer (score 43):

Here is a [good description](http://www.grammarmudge.cityslide.com/articles/article/1026513/8913.htm) of when to use shall:

> ...shall is used for the future tense
>   with the first-person pronouns I and
>   We:  I shall, we shall.  Will is used
>   with the first-person (again, I refer
>   to traditional usage) only when we
>   wish to express determination.  The
>   opposite is true for the second-person
>   (you) and third-person (he, she, it,
>   they) pronouns:  Will is used in the
>   future tense, and shall is used only
>   when we wish to express determination
>   or to emphasize certainty.

However, growing up as a native American speaker in Colorado, I never used "shall" in normal speech. However, I believe in questions it has become more common, e.g. *Shall we go?* but an American native speaker saying e.g. "I shall do that for you" will almost always sound affected or connote a Shakespearean context. I often have wondered in which parts of the world (England?) and which social echelons using "shall" in statements is actually still practiced by native speakers.

Comment: "I shall" sounds odd in colloquial British English too.

Comment: `shall` is used much more frequently in British English I belive, though predominantly by the upper classes.

Comment: @Noldorin that is the connotation given by the use of "shall" it seems. When imagining someone saying "You shall (not) do this.", I imagine a figure in authority attempting to be overbearing. Thinking along the lines of the 10 commandments "Thou shalt not", the word of someone in authority telling you how to do something.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair interpretation for modern usage. In the past (and strictly even now), it's a matter of grammar, though I'm not sure on the ultimate origins in Old English.

Comment: The main place I've seen the word used is in rulebooks, emphasizing the connotation of certainty; "when a penalty is called, the official *shall* place the puck at the closest face-off circle..." etc. As was said, it's all about the authoritative connotation of that word versus "will".

Comment: As an Englishman living in Ireland I'm still aware of the difference here. My Irish wife will usually say "will we go to the cinema today?" which still sounds to my ears like she's asking me to predict the future, whereas she's clearly expressing intent. Needless to say I seldom say "should we go to the cinema?" these days as it sounds to Irish ears old-fashioned and a bit snooty :)

Comment: I'm guessing you tried to avoid saying "native American speaker" lest it sound like the person was of indigenous American descent, but the adjective order in "American native speaker" just will not sit well with me.  :P

Comment: @edward-tanguay *A Concise Grammar of Contemporary English* by Randolph Quirk and Sidney Greenbaum says this: "*Will* for future can be used in all persons throughout the English-speaking world, whereas *shall* (for 1st person) is largely restricted in this usage to southern British English." (§3.37, page 47) The book is from 1973, so it won't be completely current, but that gives some relatively recent indication.

Answer (score 16):

Don't forget that 'shall' at the start of a question is used to make a suggestion:

> Shall we play tennis?

But 'will' at the start of a question does not have the same meaning:

> Will we play tennis?

Comment: "not the same meaning" is not clear enough for non-native speakers

Comment: ^Or native speakers for that matter

Comment: In this context, *shall* is a suggestion or invitation;  *Will* is seeking clarification of intent.

Answer (score 15):

The note about the usage of *shall* in the *New Oxford American Dictionary* is the following:

> There is considerable confusion about when to use *shall* and *will*.
>
> The traditional rule in standard English is that *shall* is used with first person pronouns (*I* and *we*) to form the future tense, while *will* is used with second and third persons (*you*, *he*, *she*, *it*, *they*): *I shall be late*; *she will not be there*.
>
> When expressing a strong determination to do something, the traditional rule is that *will* is used with the first person, and *shall* with the second and third persons: *I will not tolerate this*; *you shall go to school*.
>
> In practice, however, *shall* and *will* are today used more or less interchangeably in statements (although not in questions). Given that the forms are frequently contracted (*we'll*, *she'll*, etc.), there is often no need to make a choice between *shall* and *will*, another factor no doubt instrumental in weakening the distinction. In modern English, the interchangeable use of *shall* and *will* is an acceptable part of standard U.S. and British English.

When I started my classes on British English, I was taught that *I shall go home* was the future tense of *I go home*; asking to a person living in the east coast of the USA, I learned that *I shall be late* (or *I shall return*) has a slightly different meaning from *I will be late* (or *I will return*), at least in some contexts.

Comment: +1 Interesting. As an example of "will" to indicate a strong determination to do something: "Will you marry me?"

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser: Yes, indeed. Another interesting example of the way the two words are sometimes used to express different shades of meaning is the story of two (hypothetical) drowning men - one calls "I shall drown, and nobody will save me"; the other "I will drown and nobody shall save me". The former gets rescued (because he is expressing his fear); the latter does not (because he is expressing his determination to perish)!

Comment: @b.roth: the "Will" in "Will you marry me?" is a second-person verb, so it actually isn't a case of "will" being used to indicate strong determination to do something under the traditional rule.

Answer (score 10):

"Shall" originally indicated owing to do something. "Will" originally, and sometimes still, indicates a desire to do something. Eventually, they both came to indicate the future, but "will" usurped the place of "shall," at least in my part of Virginia. As far as I can tell, "'ll" has since taken the place of will. :)

EDIT: Should have included a link or two to begin with, not to mention double-checked my answer. Whoops, sorry.

Etymology of "will": http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=will

And as opposed to "shall": http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shall

Comment: "Would" indicates a desire. "Will" does not.

Comment: @Vincent: Actually, I did misremember the meaning of "shall," but will does indicate desire. I'm editing in a link.

Comment: is right. `Will` does indeed indicate desire.

Comment: +1 for the etymologies! I didn't know that site existed, looks like a great resource.

Comment: See my comment to the OP that "shall" is a legal contractual obligation (in the US defense industry) and "will" or any other word indicates just "nice to have".

Answer (score 7):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will

> Shall and will are both modal verbs in
>   English used to express propositions
>   about the future. According to the New
>   Oxford Dictionary of English, In
>   modern English the interchangeable use
>   of shall and will is an acceptable
>   part of standard British and US
>   English.

Comment: This is a bit too generalised. 'Acceptable' by whose standards?

Comment: It's not quite even true. In most dialects, *shall* and *will* are not interchangeable in first person questions.

Answer (score 4):

In some situations *will* and *shall* may point to different sources of motivation to act in a particular way—namely, an internal source versus an external source. As an example (in the third-person singular) of the compulsory aspect of *shall* versus the volitional aspect of *will*, consider this exchange from Henry James's short story "[Covering End](https://books.google.com/books?id=VYMqNHbJwK8C&pg=PA816&dq=%22Mr+Prodmore+now+sprang+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI48q3nO_xxgIVAZeICh35qgp9#v=onepage&q=%22Mr%20Prodmore%20now%20sprang%20up%22&f=false)":

> "And what has she [Cora Prodmore, Mr. Prodmore's daughter]," he [Mr. Prodmore] appealed, "expected *me* to give up? What but the desire of my heart and the dream of my life? Captain Yule announced to me but a few minutes since his intention to offer her his hand."
>
> She [Mrs. Gracedew] faced him on it as over the table. "Well, if he does, I think he’ll simply find—"
>
> "Find what?" They looked at each other hard.
>
> "Why, that she won’t have it."
>
> Oh, Mr. Prodmore now sprang up. "She *will*!"
>
> "She won't!" Mrs. Gracedew more distinctly repeated.
>
> "She *shall*!" returned her adversary, making for the staircase with the evident sense of where reinforcement might be most required.
>
> Mrs. Gracedew, however, with a spring, was well before him. "She sha'n't!" She spoke with positive passion and practically so barred the way that he stood arrested and bewildered, and they faced each other, for a flash, like enemies.

The progression here is from Mr. Prodmore's emphatic "She *will*!"—his assertion that Cora Prodmore will marry Captain Yule of her own volition—to his even more emphatic "She *shall*!"—his assertion that she will do so under pressure from Mr. Prodmore. Though in the first instance Mr. Prodmore has no doubt that his daughter accepts the inevitability of the marriage that he intends to bring about, his authoritarian intensity increases in the second instance as he shifts from expressing confidence in her intentions to expressing confidence in his ability to force his expectations upon her.

Answer (score 3):

Collins English Dictionary defines 'will' and 'shall' as follow:

> Will: (you, he, she, it, they, or a noun as subject) used as an
>   auxiliary to make the future tense.
>
> Shall: (I or we as subject) used as an auxiliary to make the future
>   tense.

So:

- I ***shall*** be at home tonight.
- Will ***you*** come round.

Let us use 'will' instead of 'shall', if we want to emphasize. So:

- I ***will*** be ready on time, I promise.
- I do not care what your wicked stepmother says: you ***shall*** go to the ball.

But if you want to see what may happen when we reverse 'will' with 'shall', and vice versa, read the following sentences:

- I ***shall*** drown, no one will save me. (*I should like to be saved but everyone is ignoring me.*)
- I ***will*** drown, no one shall save me. (*I am determined to drown. I forbid anyone to throw a life belt.*)

Comment: The dictionary might say that, but no one uses 'shall' in AmE (it's recognizable from the Christian Ten Commandments an legal documents, but no one would naturally use it in speech or writing). I don't know about BrE.

Comment: @Mitch Collins has: **Usage**: The usual rule given for the use of shall and will is that where the meaning is one of simple futurity, shall is used for the first person of the verb and will for the second and third: I shall go tomorrow; they will be there now. Where the meaning involves command, obligation, or determination, the positions are reversed: it shall be done; I will definitely go. However, shall has come to be largely neglected in favour of will, which has become the commonest form of the future in all three persons. >> To be fair, this might be a post-2012 addition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For US English since at least forever (60's is forever, ain't it?), 'shall' is never spoken. It is recognized in legal and religious text. Dictionaries are notoriously out of date and this is one glaring example.

Comment: @Mitch (1) I was responding to your final comment about 'BrE'. (2) Glaringly out of date? It says ' However, _shall_ has come to be largely neglected in favour of _will_, which has become the commonest form of the future in all three persons.' (3) However,  'Shall we go to the cinema tonight?' can't be idiomatically substituted here in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts, such as legal contracts or formal standards, *shall* indicates an obligation or command, whereas *will* might be interpreted as an observation or prediction.

Answer (score 2):

shall/should is stronger and heavier in emphasis than will/would.
Eg. statements that I can think off right off my mind for comparison in connotation would be:

**He shall/should be doing it.**

versus.

**He will/would be doing it.**

Answer (score 1):

Another distinction I've heard people make is that "shall" implies a deliberate action and "will" implies a result ("I shall sing and the crystal will crack").  Strictly conversations, so no authorities to quote here.

Comment: Yes in some cases, no in others, but the differences, if ever they existed, have become blurred lately.