# "to resolve that sth be done" or "to resolve that sth shall be done"?

Tags: grammar, legalese, be, that

1. The Board of Directors of the company has resolved that the capital be raised from 1,000,000 € to 9,000,000 €.
2. The Board of Directors of the company has resolved that the capital shall be raised from 1,000,000 € to 9,000,000 €.

Which one is correct? Is "shall" needed as shown in the second example?

I think they might be different usages in British and American English, I ran across them very frequently. So I want to know which one is conveying the meaning better.

P.s. This structure will be used in legal context.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely "shall." Although, using it in a legal context, you should also look into the discrimination between "will" and "shall." Here's a link to another thread that discusses legal uses of those terms. 
[Will vs Shall](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/shall-and-will-in-legal-requirements?rq=1)

Comment: Use of [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) (like example 1) also expresses that something is being mandated.