# Is use of "shall" archaic?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, archaicisms, shall-will

A friend of mine, pursuing BA(Hons) in English corrected me that no one uses shall now and often it is advised to prefer the use of *should*, *would*, etc.

Although Downton Abbey is set upon a time period decades ago, the characters make use of *"shall"* frequently in their sentences, I have noticed in some British movies and shows that the character make use of *"shall"* quite often. I couldn't help but notice that I never came across and American character making use of *"shall"* in an American TV show or movie, or maybe I missed catching the character making use of it.

What is with *"shall"* in this present-day? Is it obsolete now? Was it only used until contemporary era?

Comment: [Goodness gracious! Whatever shall we do?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILGFfIAI31M)

Comment: It's not quite obsolete. There are [two productive, if minor, constructions](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63116/15299) that  _shall_ participates in; otherwise it isn't used in living speech.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use "shall" versus "will"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will)

Comment: @JohnLawler Standards documents, including [those from ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/foreword), strictly define SHALL as an absolute requirement equivalent to MUST. Per [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt): *1. MUST   This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the   definition is an absolute requirement of the specification. 2. MUST NOT   This phrase, or the phrase "SHALL NOT", mean that the   definition is an absolute prohibition of the specification.*

Comment: As I said, it occurs in legal writing. But not in English; only in legal writing.

Comment: Certainly it's exceedingly important in technical spec writing.

Comment: I have to believe that expressions such as "Well, I shall be on my way" are still fairly common.  "Will" simply doesn't sound right in such cases.

Comment: This is the first I've heard about *shall's* demise. Compare "I shall be at work until 4:00, and then I will come and look at your tractor", "I will be at work until 4:00 and then come look at your tractor", and "I shall be at work until 4:00 and then come look at your tractor". I would only use the first one, because I wouldn't substitute *will* for *shall* when composing a compound predicate anymore than I would substitute *walk* for *run*.  And yes, I used to write specs and contracts, but I don't think that has much to do with it. I'm just wired to keep obligation and volition separate.

Comment: Are you asking if it is rare/non-existant in AmEng compared to BrEng, or if "shall" is obsolete on both sides of the Atlantic? Is your undergraduate friend American by chance?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I do believe, I reckon it is rare/non-existent in AmEng unless one would be courteous to ask one to come along by speaking _'shall we?'_  .

Comment: I discussed with my friend again and she sent me: 
" "Shall" cannot be considered as an obsolete word nor it is an archaic word.
It is used with 3rd person + ing 
Both arer modals but they have a similar usage.
I just said its not used much these days."

This whole discussion on 'shall' is getting more confusing. :/

Comment: You MUST not pass.
You MUST not murder.
You MUST not steal.
These examples sound better than “SHALL not”
to my ears.
Perhaps I’m just a frustrated editor.
Shall I go on? (Just kidding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*shall*, verb –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=shall%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> (in the first person) expressing the future tense.
> "this time next week I shall [**(will)**] be in Scotland"

Personally, I shall allow *shall* to become archaic only over my dead body. It's not that I shouldn't or that I won't; I *will*.

The only time it replaces *should* is in the idiom *"shall I..."*

> **Admiral Piett:** "Shall I hold them?"
>
> **Lord Vader:** "No. Leave them to me."

I can't think of any instance where it should replace *would*.

Comment: Shall we consider this a bit further? It doesn’t replace *should* in first-person interrogatives. It has a different nuance.

Comment: I believe we both just validated that it is not archaic. See its nuances [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63086/i-will-or-i-shall?lq=1).

Comment: the language of Piett / Vader is indeed deliberately meant to sound archaic.  they're an *Empire*, recall.

Comment: @Joe Blow: And why should an empire be considered archaic?  Unless your idea of archaic is close to "but that's so 15 minutes ago" :-)

Comment: In U.S. English it is rarely used, although in some quarters it shall be long appreciated.

Comment: [Admiral Piett](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0171829/) in the Empire Strikes back  is played by a Mancunian (British) actor. The link you posted underneath the OP's question is from Peter Pan, written by J.M. Barrie. How about finding some American English examples? :)

Comment: @KWinker: Whose US English are we talking about?  That of literate people, or the argot of the streets, in which 800 words are enough, if three of them are 'bitch', 'ho', and 'mofo'?

Comment: @jamesfq, you are right -- I should have placed that in the context of "In my experience." However, that experience is much more on the literate people end of the spectrum than the other. (length restrictions make me continue in another comment...)

Comment: And I find that my experience is echoed by Oxford Dictionaries (here http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/09/will-versus-shall/) when considering the situation in the U.S. (under The View from America):  (length restrictions, 2/3)...

Comment: "When talking about the future, will is dominant and shall seems to have fallen into disuse. According to Garner’s Modern American Usage, shall is ‘peripheral’ and occurs mainly in questions expressing suggestions or seeking agreement and in legal usage (see above). Garner also states that ‘in law it is declining because of increased recognition of its hopeless ambiguity as actually misused by lawyers’." (3/3)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I was waiting for someone to call me out on the British Admiral; didn't know the bit about Pan though. All "British" sayings in Star Wars are now common place American English. That alone answers the question IMO.

Answer (score 5):

In my (BrE*) speech "shall" is very much alive. In normal speech I say "I'll", but if I have reason to expand it, I'm as likely to say "I shall go" as "I will go".

And in a question, "Shall I" is much more natural than "Will I": I would say "will I" only when asking about a prediction or whether I will have permission or ability to do something in the future.

*Actually, this is one place where "British English" is an inadequate term, because Scottish English is different: many Scottish people do not use "shall" at all, even in permission questions: "Will I open the window?"

Comment: The last bit of what you said is interesting. I'm sure you're right, but I've never heard "Will I open the window?" before, and am not even sure I would understand its meaning immediately.

Answer (score 2):

As a middle-aged American from the Northeast, I can confirm that the use of “shall” is alive (if not entirely well) among my cohort of speakers. I’m most inclined to use “shall” in an interrogative (shall I go to the store?) where in my usage the alternative (should I go?) implies an urgency or necessity (we’re all out of milk e.g.).

I’m just reporting here the style of usage I learned as a child, haven’t vetted it for its “correctness“. However, I do have the sense that the usage of “shall” is on the decline in popular American culture.

Answer (score 2):

*Shall* is common in legal texts and related areas of writing, such as standards and specifications.

So common, in fact, that lawyers and judges are in constant debate as to its meaning. This alone is enough to make the word immortal.

A google search for “legal meaning of shall” should be enough to convince anyone. I chose the example below because I kind of like the University of Florida, but it’s one among many.

https://facultyblogs.law.ufl.edu/state-supreme-court-case-fuels-debate-over-shall-and-a-possible-solution-to-the-shall-problem/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you become familiar with [Google nGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) and with Google Books for this sort of question. Here is your answer in graphical form.

**American English**

[image]

**British English**

[image]

**A search on Google Books**

Search terms are ["shall" 21st century](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shall%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03PvXephga1OLAzjzsrs3N5VkO_FA:1606586684879&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWppzl6aXtAhWJUMAKHYp2CikQpwUIJQ&biw=1280&bih=620&dpr=1.5)

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest adding a pronoun because the gap between ["Shall I?" and "Will I?"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+I%2Cshall+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is narrower than "they shall" and "they will"

Answer (score 0):

I would think most speakers would use the contractions "I'll" or "we'll or "you'll" or "they'll", in most conversations.  And if you asked them whether they were contracting 'shall' or 'will' and asked for a RAPID response. . .I doubt you'd get one.  If my surmise proved correct, the ambivalence would suggest "shall" is on the cusp, but not archaic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Gandalf's

> YOU SHALL NOT PASS!

would have sounded quite so authoritative any other way.

Comment: **Do NOT pass** go. Do not collect £200... sounds pretty authoritative to me. He could have easily said "You will *not* pass" and the meaning would not have changed. J.R.R. Tolkien (British) also wrote LOTR in the 1950s... Would an American modern-day hero say those same words?

Comment: @Mari-LouA First off, [Gandalf didn’t use *shall* there in the book](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35262/where-did-you-shall-not-pass-come-from). But quite honestly, the *shall* would make sense there, at least to me, because for me *shall* carries a strong sense of command, or of something inevitable. Think of the KJV Ten Commandments with all their *thou shalt not* commands, for example.

Comment: @tchrist KJV was written in the late 15th century.... so would a modern-day American hero ever say: "You shall not get away with it!" ;) I don't think so.