# When should one use “shall” and "will”?

Tags: future, will-future, shall-future

When should one use “shall” and "will”?

> 'Sure, I __________ come.'

Which word - "shall" or "will" - should be used in the blank?

Comment: Sha'll is so antiquated that it sounds snobbish to use.  Like being mugged by someone saying, **Give me thy money**  You sha'll not have it any longer!

Comment: @dockeryZ What the frob is “sha’ll”?

Comment: which proper word in this blank  sure, i _______ com. shall or will

Comment: Shall is so uncommon where I'm from that I didn't even realize my err.  @ManishkumarPatel, just use `will`.

Comment: Probably you say Sure, I'll come in spoken language.

Answer (score 1):

The Longman English Grammar says: The simple future tense is formed with will in all person forms. The auxiliary shall can be used with I and we as a variant.
Unfortunately the grammar does not give a hint how learners should handle the use of shall for future.

I would say forget the shall-future. It is a system that is vanishing. All the same you find it in written English by some authors. Today shall has a touch of elevated style.

What was the cause for the use of shall for future of the first person (I and we)? "will" originally is a verb that expresses volition.
If you will (intend) to do something then the normal consequence is that you will (future) do it. In this way "will" was adopted as auxiliary for future tense.

But in the first person (I, we) "will" is ambiguous. It can express volition or future. That's why  "shall" was used in the first person. By the way, "shall" is the normal auxiliary for future in Dutsch ( zullan).
Today the use of "shall" for future is becoming a bit old-fashioned or formal.

Comment: Did you by any chance mean _Dutch_, in which we find the verb _zullen_, or is there actually a _zullan_ in a _Dutsch_?

Comment: Couldn't you **format** your answers a little bit better? E.g: Today *shall* has a touch of elevated style; reads easier than in your post. Place a single asterisk * before and after the word, or highlight the term, click the ***I*** character in the editing toolbox and voilà *italics*!

Answer (score 1):

In today's English, *will* is always correct and *shall* is always problematic in one way or another -- except in specific idioms, quotations and set phrases with an established wording, e.g. "What shall we do with a drunken sailor?".

**Background**

*Will* and *shall* were once two ordinary full verbs that had the same meaning as their German cognates *wollen* and *sollen*. For *will*, the old sense (volition, what you want to do) has survived in the noun *will* (*last will and testament*) and in *would [like]*. For *shall*, the old sense (obligation, what you are supposed to do) has survived in *should*.

For some reason, these and similar verbs have gone through a series of weird changes of meanings. (Not just in English. The Dutch cognates *willen* and *zullen* have gone through a similar but different process. Among the three major West-Germanic languages, only German has preserved the original meanings.)

Proto-Germanic did not have a future tense; futurity was expressed using the present tense together with words such as *tomorrow*. (English still does this with present progressive, though not in the same generality.)

Even with their original meanings, *will* and *shall* could sometimes be used to express futurity:

> Tomorrow I shall (= am obliged to) go to the office.
>
> Tomorrow you will (= want to) celebrate your birthday.
>
> Tomorrow he will (= wants to) celebrate his birthday.

Through overuse this led to a system in which *shall* could be used also to express *pure* futurity in the first person, and *will* could be used to express pure futurity in the second and third person. Initially the original volition/obligation senses survived as shades of meaning that were active only in certain situations. Also, one could still make the non-standard choice when expressing futurity shaded by volition or obligation:

> Tomorrow I will (= want to) go home.
>
> Tomorrow you shall (= are obliged to) see me in my office.
>
> Tomorrow he shall (= is obliged to) see me in my office.

But later these distinctions were lost and in some cases even *reversed*. (I would really like to know how that happened.) More recently, the auxiliary used for pure futurity was standardised to *will* in all persons.

As a result of the partial reversal of the volition/obligation connotations of *will/shall*, now that all of them have become mostly obsolete, it is generally unsafe to rely on them at all. For instance, most people don't seem to be aware that "What shall we do with a drunken sailor?" once carried a connotation of "What are we supposed to do with a drunken sailor?" rather than "What do we want to do with a drunken sailor?".

Therefore it is best not to use *shall* to express futurity at all.

Answer (score 0):

Shall has 4 possible occurrences.  Yet it will be always a verb.

### Questions

> Shall I/you/he/she/they/we go?

vs

> Should we go?

They each mean the same thing, but the first sentence is just simply... eloquent.

### Expressing a demand or command

> None shall pass

The sentence above has a regal tone to it, a lot of expressed power.  Yet it can also be used to *demand* that something succeeds.

> You shall win the lottery.

Saying this would give someone the impression that you have the power over the lottery.  Then again, it can also be said for good wishes.

> We shall succeed

### Demanding the future

> I/You/He/She/They/We shall see.

This use of *shall* is used to suggest that something **will** happen, but it's more demanding, and full of egotism.

> They will eat cake tomorrow
>
> They shall eat cake tomorrow.

Both sentences mean the same thing, but the one with *sha'll* suggests that the speaker/writer has the power to allow them to eat the cake.

> We will leave tomorrow
>
> We shall leave tomorrow

Again, the *shall* sentence is just a bit more demanding, in an eloquent way.  It's as if the word itself is telling everyone to be prepared, that there isn't a choice.

Comment: **–1** for a made-up non-word “sha’ll”.

Comment: Let us ignore the typo sha'll and concentrate on the question. Dockery gives an answer that covers my experience rather well. Shall has a hint of expectation about it that will does not have. Those who claim shall to be obsolete are taking from the language and adding nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As you are from India, we use 'will' everywhere instead of using 'shall' some places. but most commonly 'shall' can be used with 'I' and 'We' and 'Will' with rest.

Answer (score 0):

Although use of *shall* is increasingly rare, it is perfectly legitimate to use it in the example sentence, particularly if you wish to emphasize certainty. To my mind, *shall* is predictive and does not carry the same connotations of intent that can attach to *will*.

(Others may disagree. My opinion is formed by my experience as an engineer used to authoring requirements documents. Many engineering organisations, including NASA, explicitly differentiate between the meanings of *shall* and *will* in their documentation. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will#Legal_and_technical_use))