# "Will" vs "Would" in the sentence

Tags: word-choice, sentence, modal-verbs, construction

> On the Day of Judgement when nothing but God's justice WILL reign
>   supreme.

or

> On the Day of Judgement when nothing but God's justice WOULD reign
>   supreme.

Which of the two is correct? Also feel free to point out any other possible mistakes in the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical, with slightly different meanings: *will* is making a prediction: this is what will happen **when** the day comes. *Would* is contingent: this is what would happen **if** the day came.

(I presume the change from God to Allah was not what you were talking about).

Comment: I know that "this is would would happen if they day came" is just a series of typos and you intended to write, "this is what would happen  if the day came," but more seriously, what is your opinion of the use of "shall" instead of "will"? I'm curious what you think. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Why not post a new question?

Comment: Thank you @MarkHubbard: typos corrected (teach me to reread before posting!) I don't think I can answer your question without more context: I agree with Rathony.

Comment: A quick search turned up this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will Thank you.