# Is the word "with" strictly necessary?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I just published a "read me" file with a piece of software I wrote. In the file, I describe an interaction between the user and the computer:

> Simply run:
>
> `tpot http localhost:8080`
>
> and you shall be greeted:
>
> `tpot connected | https://nz2v6g7o.tpot.sgnl24.com`

My friend believes the word "with" is necessary between "greeted" and the colon. I believe it is not.

Is it, and why or why not?

(Also, I'm not entirely sure what tag is most appropriate.)

Comment: Hi Sean. "greeted with" is better, We don't greet someone something. we greet them **with** a drink or **with** a 'hug'. (Or we used to.) More importantly, it should be **you will** (or "you'll"), not "you shall".

Comment: @OldBrixtonian What’s wrong with “you shall”?

Comment: @Xanne "You shall" is very resolute. "You SHALL go to the ball" is what the fairy godmother says to Cinderella. This is a concise explanation: https://www.lexico.com/grammar/shall-or-will The differences between *will* and *shall* are interesting and are often mentioned hereabouts. There's a good discussion here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will