# Meaning of "shall be of" in regulation language

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, technical, shall-will

There is an interesting style in some regulations e.g, in NFPA (National Fire Protection Association) I often see "shall be of".

For instance; Sprinklers shall be of the open or automatic type, or the water supply shall be of a quantity to supply all the discharge devices.

This "shall be of", especially "of", always confuses me. Could you please help me understand it?

Comment: Related: [When should I use "shall" versus "will"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will) Sprinklers don't have any motivations, so 'will' isn't appropriate. The clauses are *stipulations* about what the appliances *are*, not what they will do in the future.

Comment: 'Sprinklers shall be of the open or automatic type' = 'Only 'open' or 'automatic' types of sprinklers are allowed'.

Comment: Within a requirement, *shall be* = must be. *Of* here shows belonging to that sort (of sort X), or a category or value: of top quality, of pure copper, of questionable morals.